# How to decide whether F is orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing as a diffeomorphism onto its image.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $U$ be the open set $(0,∞)×(0,2π)$ in the $(r,θ)$-plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We define $F : U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $F (r, θ ) = (r \cos θ , r \sin θ )$.

How to decide whether F is orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing as a diffeomorphism onto its image?

I know that an automorphism $f : V \rightarrow V$ is said to be orientation-preserving (or orientation-reversing) if it maps a basis to another basis of the same (or the opposite) orientation.

But I dont know how to apply this definition to this question.

Please explain the reason why $F$ is orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing in an explicit and instructive way. Thank you.

Comment: Please explain explicitly and informatively what you know (definitions would be a start), and what you've tried.  You know the "routine" by now.

Comment: @amWhy for president!

Comment: Okay. Sorry I forgot to write my konwledge. @amWhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

If the Jacobian matrix has negative determinant then it is orientation *reversing*. If it has positive determinant then it is orientation *preserving*.

The Jacobian matrix, in this case, is the two-by-two matrix whose columns are $F_{r}$ and $F_{\theta}$. Can you find the partial derivatives, put them in a matrix and find its determinant?

You may find that the Jacobian is singular at some point.

Comment: I know this rules. But I cannot apply these to my question. I cannot show. Please can you teach me how to show/apply these rules to my question?

Comment: What? I am confused too much:(

Comment: You have $F = (r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. What are the two partial derivatives $F_{r}$ and $F_{\theta}$? (They will be vectors.)

Comment: $F_{θ}=-rsinθdθ+rcosθdθ$ and $F_{r}=cosθdr+sinθdr$

Comment: I found these. Okay! Then, what Will I do?

Comment: Is the determinant equal to $r$?

Comment: We're working out partial derivatives here, not differentials. So $\partial F/\partial r = (\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $\partial F / \partial \theta) = (-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta).$ These are *vectors*. Now put them into a matrix. Put $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ as your first column and $F_{\theta}$ as your second.

Comment: Exactly! The determinant is $r$. So if $r>0$ then the diffeomorphism is orientation preserving. If $r=0$ the map fails to be a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Okay! I understand well:) solving together is so useful to learn:)) thank you so much:))

Comment: @B11 You're welcome!